# Dbset as hashset in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to merge data from tables in the database with data based on some logic from third-party sources. I implemented this logic via hashset, for which I overloaded the GetHashCode and Equals methods for entities. Now I don't understand how I can save the result of work in the database via DbSet, with subsequent data loading and subsequent merging (the task of merging/supplementing is periodic)

The directories are quite voluminous, so working through hashset speeds up the process.

```
    class Program
    {
        private class DummyDbContext { public void SaveChangesAsync() { }}

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbContext = new DummyDbContext(); // TODO: Get from DI

            // TODO: I don't know how to do it yet with HashSets
            var currentFactories = LoadCurrentFactoriesFromDb(dbContext);
            var currentProducts = LoadCurrentProductsFromDb(dbContext);

            var thirdPartyData = GetThirdPartyData();

            foreach (var data in thirdPartyData)
            {
                /*
                 In reality, the logic is more complicated, because some data transformation is required.
                 Some data may be missing. That is why comparing two objects is not quite easy (see the method Product.Equals)
                 */
                var factory = new Factory(data.otherFactory.Name); 
                var product = new Product(data.otherProduct.Property1, data.otherProduct.Property2, factory);

                if (currentFactories.TryGetValue(factory, out var existedFactory))
                    factory = existedFactory;
                else
                    currentFactories.Add(factory);

                if (currentProducts.TryGetValue(product, out var existedProduct))
                {
                    if (!existedProduct.Factory.Equals(factory))
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(); // TODO:
                    product = existedProduct;
                    factory.Products.Add(product); // TODO:
                }
                else
                    currentProducts.Add(product);
            }

            // **how to implement the saving of combined directories, in hashsets, in the database ?**
            dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<(ThirdPartyFactory otherFactory, ThirdPartyProduct otherProduct)> GetThirdPartyData()
        {
            return new (ThirdPartyFactory otherFactory, ThirdPartyProduct otherProduct)[]
            {
                ( new ThirdPartyFactory () {Name = "SomeFactory"}, new ThirdPartyProduct() {Property1 = "ProductName1"}),
                ( new ThirdPartyFactory () {Name = "SomeFactory"}, new ThirdPartyProduct() {Property1 = "ProductName2"}),
                ( new ThirdPartyFactory () {Name = "SomeFactory"}, new ThirdPartyProduct() {Property2 = "Property1"})
            };
        }

        private static HashSet<Factory> LoadCurrentFactoriesFromDb(DummyDbContext context)
        {
            // DbContext.DbSet<Factory>.GetAll()
            return new HashSet<Factory>();
        }

        private static HashSet<Product> LoadCurrentProductsFromDb(DummyDbContext context)
        {
            // DbContext.DbSet<Product>.GetAll()
            return new HashSet<Product>();
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public Product(string property1, string property2, Factory factory)
        {
            Property1 = property1;
            Property2 = property2;
            Factory = factory;
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Property1 { get; }
        public string Property2 { get; }

        public Factory Factory { get; }

        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            var product = (Product) obj;

            return (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Property1) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(product.Property1) 
                    || string.CompareOrdinal(this.Property1, product.Property1) == 0)

                   && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Property2) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(product.Property2)
                       || string.CompareOrdinal(this.Property2, product.Property2) == 0);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(Property1, Property2).GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class Factory
    {
        public Factory(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; }

        public HashSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThirdPartyProduct
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThirdPartyFactory
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Is it possible to implement this ?** Or do I need to convert data from DbSet to HashSet and then back ? But won't I lose information about entities inside the context during such transformations ?

Comment: Why not just ...ToDictionary ()?

Comment: what will be the key ? The product has 2 properties and i need to compare them. To do this, I overloaded the Equals method. How will a dictionary be better than a hashset? Or did I not understand the sentence ?

Comment: Hash could be the key, you already assume it's unique. Dictionary has the advantage of the ToDictionary method, it's just there.

Comment: the hash is not unique, it can be repeated. That's not the question. Dictionary or hashset - how to write all this DbSet, that's the question.

Comment: You seem to push yourself into reinventing the wheel. Don't make the HashSet into the db, it's DbSet that does that.